# Python DataFrame: Change status of a row in df based on conditions from another df?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I have two df's, One with `students details` and another df with `students attendance` records.

details_df

```
        name          roll     start_day     last_day
    0   anthony        9       2020-09-08    2020-09-28
    1   paul           6       2020-09-01    2020-09-15
    2   marcus        10       2020-08-08    2020-09-08
```

attendance_df

```
        name         roll     status       day
    0    anthony        9      absent       2020-07-25      
    1    anthony        9      present      2020-09-15
    2    anthony        9      absent       2020-09-25
    3    paul           6      present      2020-09-02
    4    marcus        10      present      2020-07-01     
    5    marcus        10      present      2020-08-17
```

I trying to get `status=absent` True/False for each user between `start_day and last_day`.

Ex: user - `anthony` has two records in `attendance_df` between start_day and last_day out of total `3` records.
From those two records if `status=absent` then mark that user as True

Expected Output

```
        name          roll      absent
    0   anthony        9         True
    1   paul           6         False
    2   marcus        10         False
```

I have tried making details_df into a list then looping into attendance_df. But is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `merge` (i.e. a join operation) and filter the days for which the column `day` is between `start_day` and `last_day`. Then, a group-by + apply (i.e. grouped aggregation operation):

```
merged_df = attendance_df.merge(details_df, on=['name', 'roll'])
df = (merged_df[merged_df.day.between(merged_df.start_day, merged_df.last_day)]
        .groupby(['name', 'roll'])
        .apply(lambda x: (x.status == 'absent').any())
        .reset_index())
df.columns = ['name', 'roll', 'absent']
```

To get:

```
df
      name  roll  absent
0  anthony     9    True
1   marcus    10   False
2     paul     6   False
```

Answer (score -1):

`Merge`, `groupby()` and find any days that are between `start` and `last` using a `lambda` function

```
df2=pd.merge(attendance_df,details_df, how='left', on=['name','roll'])
df2.groupby(['name','roll']).apply(lambda x: (x['day'].\
between(x['start_day'],x['last_day'])).any(0)).to_frame('absent')



               absent
name    roll        
anthony 9       True
marcus  10      True
paul    6       True
```